# return type for controller method in play framework 1.2.5

Tags: playframework-1.x

I am using play framework 1.2.5.  I am using a helper method being called from the controller (its in the controller - I am not sure if it really belongs in the model or elsewhere) but its return type is void.  I believe that causes the controller to return from that method and not get back to the calling method (from where the helper was called).  Besides passing a return type like int or boolean, is there anything else I can do to avoid this issue?

```
public class TestController extends Controller {

public static controllerMethod() {
helperMethod();
}

public static void helperMethod() {
    //some code 
    }

}
```

I am guessing I can either move the helper method into a model or simply pass in boolean/int as return type - any other suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `controllerMethod`, you have to call some render method :

```
public static controllerMethod() {
  helperMethod();
  render() // or ok() to return http code 200
}
```

And declare your `helperMethod` private.  Making the method private prevents the browser redirection behaviour of normal controller methods.

Comment: I might not have shared all the info - simply calling the helperMethod  which returns void ends up being redirected to the browser - thank you for your suggestion

Comment: With Play, a call to public static method in a Controller IS a redirection, so it's normal.

Comment: accepting @Thierry's answer - I also feel that Tom is also correct that I should probably move this out of the controller.  Thanks to both for sharing!

Comment: interesting, i didn't realize that making a method private changed the behaviour of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want any extra helper methods or variables in your Controller classes!  Move it to a Model class (the model class does not even have to extend Model - just don't extend Controller).

Each call to a controller method is *not* like a normal Java method invocation.  It does a lot of extra stuff and forces the browser to redirect to the method.  It will never resume the code in your original method!

So code like this in a controller method (where computeSomething is a static method of the controller)

```
  ...
  computeSomething();
  renderText("this will never be shown")
```

The only time you want to call another method in the controller is if you want to do a redirect.  A typical example is checking authentication and redirecting to a login page.

Comment: yes it does redirect - the only way I could get it to avoid this is by passing a return type from the helper method.  I think I will move this to a model and accept the answer unless someone comes up with another solution - thanks!

Comment: a good rule of thumb is:  the less code you put in a controller class the better! controllers should be kept as 'glue' - keep all your logic/etc elsewhere :)

Comment: I agree - I was being lazy and dumb in equal proportions.  thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

You can choose to use the helper method without the browser having access to it by annotating the helper method with @Util

```
public class TestController extends Controller {

public static controllerMethod() {
     helperMethod();
}

@Util
protected static String helperMethod() {
    //some code 
    }

}
```